# Join two dataset keeping only the first row of perimeter dataset that match some data condition in PySpark

Tags: windows, join, pyspark, left-join, inner-join

Is there a way to join 2 dataset without explode rows? I need only a flag if at least one row of dataset "df2" satisfies the join condition with the dataset of "df1".

Is there any way to avoid the join? I would like to avoid joining and then just keep the first row with a window function.

Condition left join is = `[(df2.id == df1.id) & (df2.date >= df1.date)]`

Example:

`Input df1`

| id | city | sport_event | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | London | football | 2022-02-11 |
| def | Paris | volley | 2022-02-10 |
| ghi | Manchester | basketball | 2022-02-09 |

`Input df2`

| id | num_spect | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 100.000 | 2022-01-10 |
| abc | 200.000 | 2022-04-15 |
| abc | 150.000 | 2022-02-11 |

`Output NOT DESIDERED` **<- NOT DESIDERED**

| id | city | sport_event | date | num_spect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | London | football | 2022-02-11 | 100.000 |
| abc | London | football | 2022-02-11 | 200.000 |
| abc | London | football | 2022-02-11 | 150.000 |
| def | Paris | volley | 2022-02-10 |  |
| ghi | Manchester | basketball | 2022-02-09 |  |

`Output DESIDERED` **<- DESIDERED**

| id | city | sport_event | date | num_spect | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | London | football | 2022-02-11 | 100.000 | 1 |
| def | Paris | volley | 2022-02-10 |  |  |
| ghi | Manchester | basketball | 2022-02-09 |  |  |

Comment: you can't avoid the join because it is needed to associate the data. but in your desired output, what is the explanation for only selecting num_spect 100.000

Comment: do you only want the first matching num_spect value by date order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my implementation using left join

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("abc", "London", "football", "2022-02-11"),
        ("def", "Paris", "volley", "2022-02-10"),
        ("ghi", "Manchester", "basketball", "2022-02-09"),
    ],
    ["id", "city", "sport_event", "date"],
)
df1 = df1.withColumn("date", F.col("date").cast(DateType()))

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("abc", "100.000", "2022-01-10"),
        ("abc", "200.000", "2022-04-15"),
        ("abc", "150.000", "2022-02-11"),
    ],
    ["id", "num_spect", "date"],
)
df2 = (df2
    .withColumn("num_spect", F.col("num_spect").cast(DecimalType(18,3)))
    .withColumn("date", F.col("date").cast(DateType()))
)

row_window = Window.partitionBy(
    "df1.id",
    "city",
    "sport_event",
    "df1.date",
).orderBy(F.col("num_spect").asc())

final_df = (
    df1.alias("df1")
    .join(
        df2.alias("df2"),
        on=(
            (F.col("df1.id") == F.col("df2.id")) 
            & (F.col("df2.date") >= F.col("df1.date"))           
        ),
        how="left",
    )
    .withColumn(
        "flag",
        F.when(
            F.col("df2.id").isNull(),
            F.lit(None),
        ).otherwise(F.lit(1)),
    )
    .withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(row_window))
    .filter(F.col("row_num") == 1)
    .orderBy(F.col("df1.id"))
    .drop(F.col("df2.id"))
    .drop(F.col("df2.date"))
    .drop(F.col("row_num")) 
)

final_df.show()
```

OUTPUT:

```
+---+----------+-----------+----------+---------+----+
| id|      city|sport_event|      date|num_spect|flag|
+---+----------+-----------+----------+---------+----+
|abc|    London|   football|2022-02-11|  150.000|   1|
|def|     Paris|     volley|2022-02-10|     null|null|
|ghi|Manchester| basketball|2022-02-09|     null|null|
+---+----------+-----------+----------+---------+----+
```

Comment: Thank u. This is my approach for now but a lot of data create a slowly computation! I thought there is a way to solve it without complete join (joing only one match row of second dataset)

Comment: @Jresearcher  you can group the records in Input df2 by id, date and that can limit the amount of records in the join. but in this case it will still be 2 matching records from Input df2 because of the different dates

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents:

1.Create the data frames as follows:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("abc", "London", "football", "2022-02-11"),("def", "Paris", "volley", "2022-02-10"),("ghi", "Manchester", "basketball", "2022-02-09")],
    schema = ["id", "city", "sport_event", "date"]
).withColumn("date", fx.col("date").cast(DateType()))

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("abc", "100.000", "2022-01-10"),("abc", "200.000", "2022-04-15"),("abc", "150.000", "2022-02-11")],
    schema = ["id", "num_spect", "date"]
)   .withColumn("num_spect", fx.col("num_spect").cast(DecimalType(18,3)))\
    .withColumn("date", fx.col("date").cast(DateType())) .orderBy(col('date'))
```

2. Then join based on the condition and then drop duplicates, finally update the column flag based on num_spect value:

   ```
   df_joined = df1.join(df2, [(df1.id == df2.id) & (df1.date >= df2.date)], how = 'left').drop(df2.date).drop(df2.id).dropDuplicates(["id", "city", "sport_event", "date"])
   df_joined = df_joined.withColumn('flag', when(col('num_spect').isNotNull(),1).otherwise(0))
   ```
3. Print the data frame
   df_joined.show()

Please refer the below screenshot for your reference:

[image]